# Specify todays date in REST API call when getting data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am using Power BI and getting data from a REST API.  I want to specify the date range for the results to be from a specified end date to todays date.  What is the correct syntax for this?   I have tried TODAY() but that does not appear to work and need the date time to be in the format below.

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://mywebsite.com/v1/site/1/records?startDate=2019-05-10T00:00:00.000Z&endDate=TODAY()"), 65001)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

[TODAY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/today-function-dax) function is DAX function, while this is M code and you should use corresponding [date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-functions). Also, you put TODAY() between the quotes, so it will be sent as is.

You could change your code to look like this:

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://mywebsite.com/v1/site/1/records?startDate=2019-05-10T00:00:00.000Z&endDate=" & Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T00:00:00.000Z")), 65001)
```